# Obtain float[] or int[] from BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I am trying to use the tone mapping code [here](https://github.com/krisher/Path-Tracer/blob/ede62288b84f4f29b21d6c8b4d6335a1a5f491f4/src/main/java/edu/rit/krisher/raytracer/image/ImageUtil.java). It has a function:

```
public void toneMap(final float[] image, final byte[] rgbOut) {
         for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            final float clamped = Math.max(0, Math.min(1f, image[i]));
            rgbOut[i] = (byte) (0xFF & (short) (clamped * 255.0));
         }
      }
```

It takes in a float array and a byte array of images and clearly applies a simple clamping to the pixel values. 
I tried:

```
int[]rbg=((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

But I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
```

Other stackoverflow answers have clearly explained as to why it was so.

I have an image file want to apply this function to that file. I know that I can read the image into a `BufferedImage` using `ImageIO.read()`. But how do I get a `float[] rgb` from it?
Is it possible? Or are there any other libraries available which can help me do this conversion from image to a `float[] rgb` array of pixels?

**EDIT:**

As few people have mentioned in their comments that the code above would do nothing to the pixel values as they are in range of 0..255. But I want to apply above code to HDR images, like the .exr format image , which have an infinite range.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? The values of your image will already be in the [0...255] range (for any normal 8 bit gray or 24/32 bit RGB/RGBA image). You can of course just apply the opposite transformation if you like (for each `value[i]`, `floatValue[i] = value[i] / 255.0f`), but you'll still end up with the same pixel values.

Comment: @haraldK thank you very much! I am struggling with a client's requirement to apply tone mapping to all image formats. He was adamant for it, hence I tried to search it out. But what abt HDR images like .exr files? would they be in 0...255 range?

Comment: From the code you show its not clear what you want to do. For a given BufferedImage, the equivalent code of the toneMap() method you show, would do absolutely *nothing* to the pixels of the image, as haraldK already tried to tell you.

Comment: Can you read .exr or other HDR formats into a `BufferedImage` with higher precision than 8 bits/sample? If you can, then tone mapping makes sense. But not the method you quote in your question, it simply clamps the values into the displayable range. You need to use one of the other algorithms in the link you posted.

Comment: Can you provide some information about the `getType()` of the resulting BufferedImage, and particularly its `getSampleModel()`? The data is obviously stored as bytes, so it's not clear whether these bytes encode, for example, float values. A small (!) example image of the type that you are using would be perfect.

Comment: @haraldK you are right.ImageIO.read() returns null for .exr file.Also after going through the documentations, I dont think BufferedImage supports HDR formats. But then if tone mapping does does not make sense at all for the common image formats, then where can the code in the link be applied?

Comment: @rahulserver One common way to create HDR images, is to combine multiple exposures of the same scene (ie., compute the `float` values based on input from  multiple images' `byte` values).